# What are most graceful alternatives to constant interfaces?

Tags: java, constants

I had been looking at some code developed by an off-shore group. I see at least one "constant interface" per module defined.
Example (not real world) :

```
public interface RequestConstants{
  //a mix of different constants(int,string,...)
  public static final int MAX_REQUESTS = 9999;
  public static final String SAMPLE_REQUEST = "Sample Request";
}
```

Per my understanding it is an anti-pattern as these does not any utility in run-time, and should be avoided or tackled in a different way.
What are elegant ways to represent this? Can `enums` be used instead?

Comment: Wow! down vote. but why?

Comment: I recommend rigourously testing the functionality of their programming and not worrying about issues like this until you find broken functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En enum is probably not a good idea unless all the parameters are closely related. With the two parameters in your example I'd say they are not closely enough related to qualify as an enum.

But it's not necessarily a Bad Idea to include a constants class / interface like this. It does have the advantage of being centralized, which means this configuration stuff can easily be moved outside of the program -- for instance to a properties file, a command-line decoder, a database or even a socket interface -- with minimal impact to the other classes. It's really a question of what direction the design will take.

Unless you are thinking of going down that path, however, I'd say static finals in the classes where the respective parameters are used is the way to go, as has been suggested already.

Comment: I agree.  Using enums and or classes instead of interfaces may break existing code.  I do not see it as that serious of an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 6):

I prefer to put constants in the class where they make they're most relevant, and then if I *have* to refer to them elsewhere, just do so - *possibly* using static imports if that makes sense (e.g. for `Math.PI`).

The only real reason to put constants in interfaces was to allow you to "implement" the method-free interface and get access to the constants via their simple names without any further qualification. Static imports remove that reason.

Comment: Static imports do not exactly achieve the desired effect in some circumstances.  If I have multiple classes in a .java file (e.g. nested files) each class can have its own set of constants and some of them could have overlapping names.  Using a static import would mean a conflict.

Comment: @emory: True. On the other hand, I wouldn't want to use the interface trick in that case anyway - having the same constant name meaning different things in the same file sounds like a bad idea to me.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - "The only real reason to put constants in interfaces was to allow you to "implement" the method-free interface and get access to the constants via their simple names" - Sounds very interesting. But isn't that a worse practice from an OO stand point - how does that relate in real-world? - thanks for your answer.

Comment: @ring bearer: Isn't *which* a worse practice? It's not really clear what you mean. But yes, creating interfaces just to hold constants was a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Turn the interface into a `final` class with a `private` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Use final non-instantiable class, i.e. one with a private constructor.